# Cinnamon is broken after upgrade to 13.10

Tags: kernel, python, 13.10, cinnamon

I see reports of people with Unity broken after upgrading to 13.10. In my case Unity works fine but cinnamon is broken. It opens the startup applications but no window manager, no menus and the keyboad shortcuts won't work. As a consequence I can't even log out or shut down cleanly.

The logs say:

```
Oct 19 10:32:42 Aveline colord: Profile added: icc-1727cc5030c477b20ad75593e757248d
Oct 19 10:32:43 Aveline gnome-session[9157]: WARNING: App 'cinnamon.desktop' exited with code 1
Oct 19 10:32:43 Aveline gnome-session[9157]: WARNING: App 'cinnamon.desktop' respawning too quickly
Oct 19 10:32:43 Aveline gnome-session[9157]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Oct 19 10:32:43 Aveline gnome-session[9157]: WARNING: App 'cinnamon.desktop' exited with code 1
Oct 19 10:32:46 Aveline whoopsie[1054]: online
Oct 19 10:32:53  whoopsie[1054]: last message repeated 12 times
Oct 19 10:32:53 Aveline kernel: [ 1982.637049] python[9626]: segfault at 1511 ip b6c9e850 sp bf8d0980 error 4 in libglib-2.0.so.0.3800.0[b6c5b000+102000]
Oct 19 10:32:53 Aveline kernel: [ 1982.837527] python[9631]: segfault at 0 ip b6eb13fa sp b69ff848 error 6 in libdbus-1.so.3.7.4[b6e89000+49000]
Oct 19 10:32:54 Aveline kernel: [ 1983.030271] python[9634]: segfault at a6f4098b ip b6e52389 sp bfcdad68 error 4 in libdbus-1.so.3.7.4[b6e34000+49000]
Oct 19 10:32:54 Aveline kernel: [ 1983.253259] python[9639]: segfault at 4 ip b6e710f4 sp b69c1bfc error 6 in libdbus-1.so.3.7.4[b6e4b000+49000]
Oct 19 10:32:54 Aveline kernel: [ 1983.501771] python[9642]: segfault at b4 ip b6e0f076 sp bf82524c error 4 in libdbus-1.so.3.7.4[b6dfd000+49000]
Oct 19 10:32:54 Aveline kernel: [ 1983.721334] python[9647]: segfault at 4 ip b6eab0f4 sp b69fbbfc error 6 in libdbus-1.so.3.7.4[b6e85000+49000]
```

Any idea?

Comment: Cinnamon is not Ubuntu's default GUI, so upgrading has probably not been tested, let alone supported.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new user and login using it and copy everything specially all the hidden .* config files from that new user home directory to your home directory. It will overwrite your old config files and cinnamon will work. You can remove then the new user account.